# driving directions set font size

Tags: css, font-size

I have added driving directions to my responsive site and it works well. I would like to set the font size of the directions panel but that is not working through the div in which it appears. I have tried various approaches and all have been unsuccessful so far. Is there a specific div name that I can use to set the font size in this area?

```
#directions-panel {
      height: 300px;
      float:
      right;
      width: 49%; }
 .gm-style-iw div {
      font-size: 15px !important;}
```

The javascript calling the routines was lifted directly from the sample code on the API site. The results can be viewed at http://www.linkemup.us/howellwoods/#about

Comment: Please post some code. Your question as it stands is unclear and doesn't show us what you've tried.

Comment: #directions-panel {height: 300px; float: right; width: 49%; }
.gm-style-iw div { font-size: 15px !important; }
The directions-panel div is inside of a jquery mobile page div.

Comment: Edit your question to include your code. Posting it in the comments makes it difficult to read and follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS `.gm-style-iw div` means "for any div **within** an element that has the class 'gm-style-iw'"...  That's probably not what you meant.  You probably meant `div.gm-style-iw`, which means "for any div that **has** the class 'gm-style-iw'.

Though, I'm confused as to why you don't have the font size in the selector for `#directions-panel`...

Comment: That did not change the font size of the text in the driving directions. Is there an internally defined div that I should use? It does not work for my directions-panel div.

Comment: @user3099624 It looks like you just have the font size in the wrong selector.  I've updated my post.

Comment: It did not work there initially and I had used the wrong format of important! It is there and works now. Thanks.